# KNX PROS & CONS about using same device for sensor&actuator and impact on electrical design

Tags: electrical, home-automation, new-home

Is there any recommendation to take into account about using devices that joins the sensor and the actuator instead of placing all the actuators in the electrical control panel? What are the pros and the cons?

In a new home unfamiliar building, is there any guideline to follow about this? I understand that in some cases you can save on electrical/bus wiring, but I have no idea when it could be better.

I'm talking about KNX devices. You can have a sensor (push button) that triggers an actuator that detects the sensor signal and opens/closes the lights. In this case the sensor (or interface) is placed in one room and the actuator it could be placed into the electrical control panel. These are 2 different devices. However, there are devices that have the sensor (or the interface) and the actuator. In this last case, it's placed on the room and the bus and electrical wiring differs from the first use case.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What kind of sensors and actuators are we talking here?

Comment: Looking at the edit Michael made changing "unifamiliar" to "unfamiliar". I'd agree, in general, but it could be that the OP's intent was "uni-family" or "one-family" building.